# Octave to Matlab, Error using ==> vertcat, CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent

Tags: matlab, octave

I have the following code, which runs fine in Octave:

```matlab
matrizJugadas = [ 
     '1'   '2'   '3' ; 
     '4'   '5'   '6' ; 
     '7'   '8'   '9' ;
     '10'  '11'  '12'
];
```

However, when I run the same in MATLAB, the following error is thrown:

```
The expression on this line will generate an error when executed.  The error will be:     Error    using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
 
??? Error using ==> encuentraPares at 15
Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not
consistent.
```

Why doesn't this work in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

In Octave, char arrays are automatically padded with empty char values when lengths differ. E.g.:

```
matrizJugadas = [
         '1'   '2'   '3' ;
         '4'   '5'   '6' ;
         '7'   '8'   '9' ;
         '10'  '11'  '12'
    ]

matrizJugadas =

123
456
789
101112

int32(matrizJugadas )
ans =

  49  50  51  32  32  32
  52  53  54  32  32  32
  55  56  57  32  32  32
  49  48  49  49  49  50
```

Note the extra 'blank space' characters `char(32)` padding the end of the first three rows.

it will do this whether or not created as multiline inputs as done above:

```
a = ["1","2","3"; "4","5","6","7"]
a =

123
4567

int32(a)
ans =

  49  50  51  32
  52  53  54  55
```

If you attempt to do the same thing in Matlab, you will get the errors you described:

```
 
>>  matrizJugadas = [ 
        '1'   '2'   '3' ; 
        '4'   '5'   '6' ; 
        '7'   '8'   '9' ;
        '10'  '11'  '12'
];
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

>> a = ["1","2","3"; "4","5","6","7"]
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.
```

This is a known, deliberate incompatibility between the two programs. See https://docs.octave.org/v8.2.0/Character-Arrays.html

The best workaround for you will depend on exactly where your data comes from and what you're trying to do with it.

Comment: The Octave code is probably doing something different than intended.

Comment: don't think so.  there is  a function `string_fill_char` that lets you change the fill value to something other than a blank space.  the help text for that function suggests this has been expected behavior for some time, but I can't seem to find it documented explicitly elsewhere. see  https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/string_fill_char.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t mean that Octave behaved in an unintended way. I presume that OP’s code works in an unintended way. The array they’re building doesn’t make much sense.

Comment: oh, got it, and I agree.

Answer (score 1):

This is 6 elements wide:

```
[ '10'  '11'  '12' ]
```

It's equivalent to

```
'101112'
```

and also

```
[ '1' '0' '1' '1' '1' '2' ]
```

but this is only 3 elements wide:

```
[  '1'   '2'   '3' ]
```

Comment: So, how to put this values in the same a matrix?

Comment: @CristianChaparroA.: What data type do you expect to have?  What size do you want to get?

Comment: I need to change the value  in the specific position, for example '10' to 'Q', It's possible ?.

Comment: @CristianChaparroA.: It's not clear what you want.  `'10'` is a string with two characters, it cannot fit in one position of a matrix.  You can use cell arrays, or you can store numbers (`10` instead of `'10'`) or you can add padding so that all your values take up two columns in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In matlab from R2017x single and double quotes behave a bit differently. For most of the usages they are equivalent but not for concatenation. Single quotes define a char array, double a string.

What your code is trying to do is concatenate line per line into a matrix, this implies that they must have the same dimension.
As noted in a previous answer the first line concatenated ['1','2','3'] -> ['123'] has dimension 1x3 while the third one since it's double digits is ['10' '11' '12'] -> ['101112'] which is 1x6.
Then it tries to vertcat them, but since the dimension mismatch i doesnt work.

Using double quotes you will be defining strings, that will not be concatenated.

```
matrizJugadas = ["1" "2" "3" ; "4" "5" "6" ; "7" "8" "9" ; "10" "11" "12"];
```

By using string though you have to check usages in afterwards code since as said they behave a little differently. If you need them as chars you can do this:

```
matrizJugadas = convertStringsToChars["1" "2" "3" ; "4" "5" "6" ; "7" "8" "9" ; "10" "11" "12"];
```

this will output a cell array with chars, still again cell arrays behave a little differently and you should recheck the afterwards code.

Comment: Thanks for adding an updated answer with a more recent MATLAB version. Do note though, that this question was asked in 2013, i.e. using an older MATLAB version.

Comment: i'll be honest, for some reason it appeared on top of my feed and i didn't notice the date. I thought it was a recent one